# Why are the results from this code skipping months?

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to pull up the last record from each month in the current year.  I have recordsets from the following dates:

1/18/19,1/25/19,1/31/19,2/8/19,2/15/19,2/22/19,2/28/19,3/8/19,3/15/19,3/22/19,4/5/09,4/12/19,4/26/19,5/3/19,... and so on.

When my code displays the results, it skips the records from Feb and Apr, so it only shows 1/31/19,3/29/19, and 5/31/19.  I can't quite figure out what I did wrong here since it is not displaying 2/28/19 or 4/26/19.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM production 
            WHERE YEAR(production_date_entered) = YEAR(NOW())
            AND production_date_entered IN (SELECT MAX(production_date_entered) FROM production GROUP BY YEAR(production_date_entered), MONTH(production_date_entered))
            ORDER BY production_date_entered DESC ";
$result = mysqli_query($mysqli, $sql);

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I don't know if this will solve your problem, but it suits better to your logic: `SELECT * FROM production 
WHERE production_date_entered IN (
  SELECT MAX(production_date_entered) 
  FROM production 
  WHERE YEAR(production_date_entered) = YEAR(NOW())
  GROUP BY MONTH(production_date_entered)
)
ORDER BY production_date_entered DESC`

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/wYrSDRNHVfyPe4TJLZhFpT/0

Comment: Thank you very much for your help.  I did change my code to match your suggestion, yet it is still not displaying all the results, only every other month.

Comment: This must be a php and not sql issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What happens when you change your PHP code to:

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    echo $row['production_date_entered'];
    // $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
}
```

Not an expert, but it seems that you are doing an extra fetch.  Do you have more PHP code than that to show how you are displaying / processing your results ?

Comment: Thank you very much for all your help.  I must have omitted something that I couldn't find.  I just deleted everything, retyped it all and it worked.  Thanks again everyone.